# Microsoft Access add entries to multiple tables with one form

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

I have a database in Microsoft Access 2007-2010. It's set up in 4 tables:

- A list of machines, each with an identifying number
- A list of parts, each with an identifying number, and a number that corresponds to the machine it is on
- A list of problems, each with an identifying number, and a number that corresponds to the part it occurs on
- A list of solutions, with a number that corresponds to the problem it solves and multiple fields for various information about that solution

I want to create a form that will allow you to chose a machine, then either chose an existing part or add a new part from that machine, add a new problem, or chose an existing problem, if an existing part was found, and finally add a new solution, and all the fields related to it.

I'm very inexperienced with Access, so I have no idea how to do this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user Beth suggested, subforms are designed for this type of problem. Simply create a form for each 'Level' and nest them. You need to link each form to the parent form above it by using the child properties 'Link Master Fields' and 'Link Child Fields', this is where you would link the top level MachineID from the Machine table with the next Level MachineID from the Parts table.

The question you pose is a little too broad to really be answered here, so you are best off looking at something like [This link](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA) and then coming back here to ask questions about specific problems you are having with your implementation.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Subforms are 100% what I needed. It's not quite aesthetically what I'd prefer, but it's functional, and that's what's important.